# nodejs - mongodb - Cannot call method 'collection' of null

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to query database everytime users input messages, nodejs complains "Cannot call method 'collection' of null" Below is the code I think the problem comes from.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var db = new mongo.Db('chat', new mongo.Server('127.0.0.1', '27017', {native_parser:true}));
//testting querying mongo everytime there is message
socket.on('connection', function(client) {
    client.on('message', function(message) {        
        db.open(function(err, db){
            db.collection('sessions', function(err, collection){
                collection.count(function(err, count) {
                  sys.puts("There are " + count + " records.");
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

note: the first user's message, I got the sys.puts count right, no errors. but the second input will cause error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.open(function(err, db){
    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        });
    });
});
```

As Raynos suggested putting db.open in outer of closure will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
db.open(function(err, db){
    if (err) {
        sys.puts(err);
    } else {
        db.collection('sessions', function(err, collection){
            collection.count(function(err, count) {
                sys.puts("There are " + count + " records.");
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Always check the `err` object and print it.

Comment: I put that in my code, the error output is "connection already opened"

Comment: @runrunforest your opening the database for every client that connects. Open it once.

Comment: That's what I think. I'm trying to query database in every message clients send, I have no idea to open the database once and use it in the socket.on('message') closure.